# iTextSharp - Adding a vertical textbox

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Does anyone know if it's possible to add a vertical textbox to a PDF document using itextsharp.

I have tried rotating the page first

```
PdfDictionary pDict = reader.GetPageN(1);
pDict.Put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(90));
AddTextBox(stamper, ...........)
// Rotate back
```

but this just adds the textbox horizontally, do I need to get another instance of stamper after the rotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the `TextField` set its `Rotation` property:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(file1);
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file2, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs))
    {
        TextField tf = new TextField(stamper.Writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 300), "Vertical");
        //Change the orientation of the text
        tf.Rotation = 90;
        stamper.AddAnnotation(tf.GetTextField(), 1);
    }
}
```