# How to create textbox in pdf using iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am using ASP.NET and C#.Then I am using iTextSharp for creating pdf on the fly.Can someone tell me how to create the textbox,label.Is it Possible? Because What ever i searched they are using PdfpTable and PdfpCell..

Give me some example..

EDIT:
I need to create a pdf that should look exacly like my .aspx page.I am creating on button click.If i add textfield that is in edit mode i dont want that.So i need to create the entire page as readonly in pdf?

Provide me any materials/articles/ebooks..

Thanks..

Comment: possible the duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675895/itextsharp-text-field-in-pdfpcell

Comment: In this example also they are placing textfield into table and then adding to pdf?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using this piece of code snippet:

```
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(new PdfReader(inputFile), File.Create(outputFile)))
{
    TextField tf = new TextField(stamper.Writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 300), "Vertical");
    stamper.AddAnnotation(tf.GetTextField(), 1);
    stamper.Close();
}
```

Reference: [iTextSharp - Adding a vertical textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414019/itextsharp-adding-a-vertical-textbox)

You should also take a look at iText in Action. [Chapter 8](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=8) has some examples that might be useful for you.